Has Trump made any statements giving details of who he counts as an illegal immigrant?
What is the definition of an illegal immigrant whom Trump vows to expel from the USA if he is elected a second time?
What are the criteria for a person to be considered as a candidate for deportation?
Has Trump made any statements giving details of who he counts as an illegal immigrant?

I seriously doubt that there is a clear definition. Donald Trump tends to announce plans and only then specify the details. As such, this question should be closed for asking to speculate about the state of mind of a person, or for their reaction to a hypothetical situation.

I don't know if it will help but you might try rephrasing this along the lines of "Has Trump made any statements giving details of who he counts as an illegal immigrant".

One could also look at his presidency from 2016-20. Maybe his actions/orders then make it somewhat clearer.


What is the criteria for a person to be considered as a candidate for deportation?

Assuming you mean "considered" by Trump, given the Q title.
FWTW, I think few know the exact contours of Trump's plan, but from one the sources cited the community wiki;

Trump has said he would invoke the Alien Enemies Act, a 1798 law that allows the president to deport any noncitizen from a country that the U.S. is at war with.
Texas Gov, Greg Abbott has advanced a theory that illegal immigration amounts to an invasion to justify state enforcement measures, so far without success, but legal scholars say judges may be reluctant to second-guess what a president considers a foreign aggression.
[...] The Trump campaign, asked how his pledge would be carried out, said Trump would begin the largest deportation program in U.S. history, without elaborating in detail. Karoline Leavitt, a spokeswoman, said Trump “would marshal every federal and state power necessary to institute the largest deportation operation of illegal criminals, drug dealers, and human traffickers.”

So somewhere in between any non citizen and "illegal criminals, drug dealers, and human traffickers" is the line.
BTW, the another piece in the community wiki (Newsweek) claim he said he'll deport (all?) undocumented migrants, but on searching for that "elite squads" phrase for an actual/full quote, it seems Trump was again more narrow in declaration:

Trump said in Aurora that, if he wins a second term, he would “send elite squads of ICE, Border Patrol, and federal law enforcement officers to hunt down, arrest, and deport every last illegal alien gang member until there is not a single one left in this country.”

OTOH

However, Trump and his running mate JD Vance have suggested they would not just stop at gang members. When pressed for a number, Vance previously said they would set a goal of 1 million deportations.

I'm not sure it's worth delving into what Vance (rather than Trump) said more precisely, but anyhow, Vance qualified that as: "Let's start with one million [...] And then we can go from there." So potentially more. FWTW, it's estimated there are about 11 million undocumented immigrants in the US.


BTW, there is a certain disconnect between those general claims and some specific groups Trump & Vance attacked, e.g. the Haitians in Springfield. According to non-Republican media, most of those are technically legal albeit under various temporary protection statuses ("humanitarian parole" etc.) that could be easily revoked by a US president. Vance at least somewhat more clearly said Biden has made a mistake letting those people in (like that).

"a 1798 law that allows the president to deport any noncitizen from a country that the U.S. is at war with": there are no such noncitizens since the US is not at war with any country.  "that could be easily revoked by a US president": not that easily; see his earlier attempt to revoke DACA.

@phoog: true Trump says it's easy but he had to give up the Haitian business the first time around he tried https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/11/21/us-ends-temporary-protected-status-for-55000-haitians Still, like with the Muslim ban, he'll probably be successful with enough attempts. He has more judges in pocket now too. Eventually... https://apnews.com/article/el-salvador-immigration-pasadena-courts-donald-trump-c903626adf3fcdb1d7805f560c37d1be
