Why doesn't Lebanon have a capable military to defend its territory from Israel?
Given that Lebanon sits in a very contentious region, it is reasonable to expect that they should have a capable military.
Lebanon doesn't seem to have a capable military force to defend its territory from Israeli agressions.
Why is that?

Lebanon has a military. How do you distinguish between a capable one and one that is not? This seems like a matter of opinion.

Was there any research done into this question? The country really hasn't had a peaceful existence since its independence. Its been occupied twice within the last 25 years. Depending on some definitions Hezbollah occupies part of its territory. The question is essentially asking for a modern history lesson on the country. I would recommend starting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanon

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Armed_Forces

+1.  There is probably news coverage, at least in Lebanon, of the budget/policy decisions not to invest much in it.  And those can probably be traced to a) lack of money b) considerations concerning sectarian power sharing in general and c) pushback by Hezbollah to remain the top dog in particular.  It is of interest here, as a capable enough military might have been able to keep Hezbollah from engaging in military adventurism with Israel, should the country of Lebanon as a whole find that desirable.  This is true in 2024, but it was also true in 2006.

... alternatively, rather than keeping Hezbollah out of trouble, defending Lebanon when it gets attacked by Israel.  BTW, the claim that the Lebanese army is weak is well-known and easy to find sources for : https://today.lorientlejour.com/article/1359781/could-lebanons-dysfunctional-state-put-up-a-good-fight-against-israel-without-hezbollah.html  Also... the US provides much of its funding, so make of that what you wish https://www.state.gov/u-s-security-cooperation-with-lebanon

Capable of what?  BTW, a general answer would probably not be very different from the one to the Q why they don't have advanced SAMs for example, but depending exactly what you want them to be capable of, it might be different.

@DavidS We don't have a hard research requirement.  And, yes, many of us are somewhat familiar with Lebanon - no need to be all condescending with wikipedia, which doesn't answer this question anyway - and still not exactly clear how they ended up where they can't control their territory over a militia.  I.e. let's see what answers people come up with before shooting down the very idea of a question.

@ItalianPhilosopher: given the OP's posting history here, I suspect they mean to ask why they're not capable of fighting Israel rather than Hezbollah, but it's probably best the OP clarifies. Unfortunately they have a tendency to ask these half-baked questions here and seldom improve them lately. E.g. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89629/who-is-an-illegal-immigrant-according-to-trump

I often wonder if a bit more research would result in more interesting questions because once you go beyond the obvious (Lebanon is not such a rich country and given that it's rather reasonable not to expect too much there.) there might be interesting but a bit more complex and involved questions lurking. I don't know. Like how does it come that Israel is economically so much stronger than the surrounding region. Or maybe others...

I mean just plot military spending as percentage of GDP and Lebanon is quite likely absolute average there. No surprise at all. (Actually it's rather high even but that might only be because the GDP went down lately.) The question directly translates to why is the GDP of Lebanon lower than that of Israel.

(It's a little more complicated than it appears.  BTW, sorry lots of French language links, with translations:  press coverage of Lebanon just is more prevalent in French than English.
And I've also chosen to concentrate more on the original title of this Q: "Why doesn't Lebanon have a capable military":  resisting Israeli is one possible role for the army, but so is keeping Lebanon out of trouble by stopping a militia from ensnaring Lebanon in a war it can't win and that it doesn't want)
TLDR:

Lebanon is poor, corrupt and can't afford to fund a better army.
The army is deliberately kept weak by internal politics.  And Hezbollah.
The USA, which funds a good deal of it welcomes a role for it against Hezbollah, less so against Israel.

1969 Lebanon's army loses its monopoly on violence, to the PLO
You have to go way back to start seeing this, to 1969 and the Cairo Accords, which allows forces other than the Lebanese Armed Forces (LAF) to hold military weapons at scale.
This grants the PLO the right to carry out armed resistance from Lebanon.  Wikipedia France claims they led on to the civil war.  More details, in French

It is important to mention that the Lebanese Parliament ratified the Cairo agreement without having received the text. Although the Annahar newspaper published a “full” version in April 1970, the Lebanese Minister of Information at the time, Osman Dana, did not comment on the authenticity of the document. Furthermore, an authorized Palestinian source confirmed to AFP in Beirut that the version in question was “correct”. “This agreement will remain secret and can only be revealed by the military commands of both parties,” reads the last clause.

This in turn facilitated the Lebanese civil war

Divisions among the Lebanese over the place of the PLO in their country and the distribution of political power between confessional communities ultimately led to all-out civil war on April 13, 1975.

Now, the Cairo accords were nullified later on.  And Israel invaded in 1982 and would only fully withdraw in 2000:  Hezbollah was a large factor in booting the IDF out.  And Syria invaded sometime and would only fully withdraw in 2007.
1975-1989 Lebanese civil war.

1982 Israel invades (withdraws 2000),
1982 Hezbollah is founded
? Syria invades (withdraws 2007)
the PLO loses much of it power

1989, the army re-loses the monopoly on violence, to Hezbollah
After the civil war, you get the 1989 Taif Agreement
Those ... drumroll ... repeated the same pattern, this time with Hezbollah receiving the right to armed resistance, to defend Lebanon from Israel.  Sponsors/influencers are Saudi Arabia, the US and Syria.  Most of the militias are disarmed, but Hezbollah is not.
(synthesis from some articles I forgot to bookmark)

Muslims don't trust a powerful army, fearing it would be dominated by Christians

Christians don't trust a powerful army, fearing it would be dominated by Muslims.

Syria's continuing occupation keeps the army weak for decades

Hezbollah most certainly has no interest in seeing the LAF become more powerful than itself.  It doesn't straight out claim it is competing with the LAF, it likes to claim it is a necessary addition (against Israel).


Note that while Israel is quite unpopular in Lebanon as a whole, Hezbollah is largely controlled by Iran, which views it as useful military proxy against Israel.  Yes, Hezbollah did get credit from its operations against the IDF during the 1982-2000 occupation (less so from collaborating with Syria's occupation), but it's still only really representing at most the interests of the 30% of the population that is Shiite Muslim.
And in fact, Hezbollah has also infiltrated the army:

Moreover, some LAF institutions—such as the military courts and army intelligence—are more infiltrated and controlled by Hezbollah than others. U.S. aid to these institutions could serve the militia’s interests more than the army’s capabilities and Lebanon’s stability. Washington should also pay extra attention to military and security appointments, since these play a key role in Hezbollah’s efforts to take over decisionmaking in this sector.

Basically, the army never rebuild

Lebanon, deeply scarred by the civil war from 1975 to 1990, emerged with a divided and under-equipped national army. Unlike Hezbollah, which was able to strengthen itself after this period, the Lebanese army never really recovered its pre-war capabilities.

Lebanon is just not as powerful as Israel.
Population:  5M, $11K GDP per capita vs 10M @ $54k per capita.
In addition, Lebanon is a near failed-state at this point:

How to explain this weakness? Firstly by the political crisis sweeping through the country. On October 30, 2022, the last head of state, Michel Aoun, left the presidency, without a successor. Parliament failed to find a compromise between the different political forces and nominate a candidate to replace him. Since then, there has been no President of the Republic.


Second reason: the economic and financial collapse of the country. The country has been in full bankruptcy for several years and inflation has reached a record level. “The national currency has lost more than 90% of its value in a few years, against the dollar or the euro, for example,” says Ziad Majed.

And, yes, as posited in the question, Lebanon's army is not particularly capable, though 70k troops is comparatively a fairly large contingent for a country of 5m people:

The LAF has historically stayed out of conflicts with Israel, since it lags far behind militarily in comparison. Military assessment organization Global Firepower ranks Lebanon at 118 out of 145 countries in terms of strength, while the IDF is among the organization’s list of the 20 most powerful armed forces in the world. Lebanon does not have any fighter jets and possesses only outdated tanks. It has a little more than 70,000 active troops—with many of those doing two or three jobs. Israel, in comparison, has 170,000 active-duty personnel and between 300,000 and 400,000 soldiers in reserve, as well as state-of-the-art fighter planes, tanks, and defense systems.

Note, that for the purposes of this question, much more powerful countries than Lebanon also struggle against the Israeli military, which in addition to its numerical and technological edge is just an unusually capable military.
The USA bankrolls a good deal of the LAF's budget

U.S. security assistance for the Lebanese Armed Forces (LAF) is a key component of U.S. Lebanon policy to strengthen Lebanon’s sovereignty, secure its borders, counter internal threats, and disrupt terrorist facilitation.  Key areas of cooperation include border security, maritime security, defense institution building, arms transfers, and counterterrorism.

And also...

Since 2006, the US aid to the Lebanese Army has totaled more than $3 billion, according to the US Department of State, making it the main donor to the Lebanese Army.

The LAF in fact relies on just-in-time ammo from the US.

... former general details, adding that “when the battle of Nahr al-Bared began in 2007, which I was honored to participate in, the Americans immediately supplied us with weapons, which arrived in Lebanon by planes. Had it not been the case, we would have been able to fight for just one day,” he reveals.


“So, if the army confronts the Israelis today, and runs out of ammunition after three and four days, what will it do then?”

To quote another take on that:

Elena Aoun explains: "The Lebanese army is structurally weak, because it operates in a fragile country. This weakness is also deliberately maintained by the international community. Lebanon is a poor country, and the army is equipped by actors like the United States, France and Saudi Arabia, but these are often donations of end-of-line equipment. One reason is that the West does not want Lebanon to ever pose a threat to Israel. ".


The international community has thus always ensured that the Lebanese army is effective in the fight against internal terrorism, especially in the 2010s, without ever making it a true national defense army capable of protecting Lebanese territory against incursions, notably Israelis.


I'll conclude with a bit of speculation on the above.  Could the US not have risked arming the LAF more, on the premise that the main point of contention with Israel is Hezbollah?  A more robust LAF might have disarmed Hezbollah, while still remaining well below the threshold of risk to Israel.
It is possible that the US considered that, but then they might also very well considered that too risky:  the LAF is considered by some to be infiltrated by Hezbollah and/or may have surrendered their weapons if pushed too hard.  Afghanistan, and Iran before that, shows the real risk in providing advanced weaponry to allies that don't manage to hang on to them.  And the larger Lebanese state around the LAF hardly inspires any confidence in that regard.

In 2020, Lebanon had a nominal GDP of ~19 billion [1]. At the same time, the nominal GDP of Isreal is north of 500 billion [2].
Now this begs the question why Lebanon is in this state, and that's because it has had a very troubled history. It has been ravaged by a civil war [3], was occupied to a rather large extend by Syria from 1976-2005 [4] and to a smaller extend by Israel from 1988 - 2000 [5]. Lately, it has had a major financial crisis [6], exacerbated by the Covid 19 pandemic and the 2020 Beirut Port Explosion [7].
The power struggle within Lebanon is also ongoing. You have various religious sects vying for power: Sunni Muslims, Shia Muslims, Maronite Christians, Druze and others. The Lebanese government is mainly shaped by two agreements, the 1943 National Pact [8] and the 1989 Taif Agreement [9] (the latter ended the Civil War). Under the National Pact, the power sharing was as such (abbreviated):

The President must be a Maronite Christian.
The Prime Minister must be a Sunni Muslim.
The Speaker of Parliament must be a Shia Muslim.
Parliament seats are divided 6:5 in favor of Christians (revised by the Taif agreement to 50:50).

The Taif agreement distributed certain roles anew to certains sects and also distributed parliament seats more equally.
Now, Hezbollah is a Shia political and militant group and political party. They hold seats in parliament and participate in the power sharing agreement. But they also retain an armed militia, which they claim is needed as defense against Israel, despite the Taif agreement calling for their disarmament. The Lebanese central government has no effective control over southern Lebanon and cannot challenge Hezbollah or disarm it without restarting the civil war.
So there you have it. A highly divided state that effectively has not one, but two armed forces, has no economy to speak of and is politically highly unstable. Lebanon does have a military. As of 2024 it has 80000 service members and a yearly budget of 243 million [10]. Compare to Israel's defense budget of 24.3 billion in 2021 [11].
The Lebanese government cannot prevent Hezbollah from firing into Israel. But they also do not seem to have a vested interest in preventing Israel from defeating or at least severely weakening Hezbollah. They have no reason to fight Israel along Hezbollah, so they don't [12].

References:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Lebanon
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_Isreal
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Civil_War
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrian_occupation_of_Lebanon
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_occupation_of_Southern_Lebanon
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_liquidity_crisis
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Beirut_explosion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Pact
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taif_Agreement
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Armed_Forces
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Defense_Forces
https://foreignpolicy.com/2024/10/09/lebanon-army-war-israel-hezbollah/


It does. Just not "enough" for most purposes.
Lebanon fought a civil war a generation ago. It did not end with a clear victory. Instead the different ethnic and religious groups came to a power-sharing agreement which left the central government weak and the militias and warlords strong. The Lebanese government cannot prevent Hezbollah from firing on Israel, and even trying to control them would restart the civil war.

If Germany and the USA would give as much weapons to the Lebanon as they gave to Israel, things would be quite different today, I guess.

@U.Windl Unfortunately Lebanon had no artist as a president to persuade them.

@U.Windl Give weapons to whom? There needs to be a leadership to support. The US provides weapons to a number of stable Arabs countries. That is the point.

Because the Israelis are armed and bankrolled by the most powerful conventional military on Earth, the USA, so there is an extremely high bar.
The effective limitation is largely the ability of Israel to produce and mobilise soldiers (and maintain political stability whilst doing so), and the reckoning of the US about it's interests at stake (including non-military ones, like maintaining the extraction of stored energy forms from the wider Middle East).
